# How to end all processs of one MPI communicator without closing the program?

Tags: fortran, mpi

In fortran, how do I finish only one communicator (not MPI_COMM_WORLD) without closing the program?

I've tried to do:

```
call MPI_ABORT(mpiCommGroup, ierror, ierr)
```

But the program ends

Comment: You might be looking for `mpi_comm_free`.  That disposes of the communicator, but not of the processes themselves.  Do you really want to halt some of the processes ?

Comment: do you want to release the communicator? or do you want to terminate all the tasks in that communicator? In the latter case, you might want to investigate `MPI_Comm_spawn()` to start the MPI tasks that will be released before the "main program" completes.

Comment: Supose I Have two communicators running: MPI_WORLD_COMM (works as a master process) and another one "X" (works as slave processes). I want finalize the "X" communicator and all the process. But, I don't want the MPI_WORLD_COMM be finalized.

Comment: Another information: all MPI communicators uses the same processors